# can't access module elements using geb groovy

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, spock, geb

I have a page, that is made of frames. I want to access elements of the frame and manipulate them. I want to use module to implement my changes. This is how my code looks like.

```
<html>
<body>
    <frame name="header" ></frame>
    <frame name="center" >


        <input name='quantity' type='text'>
        <input name='ok' type='radio' value='ok'>
   </frame>
  <frame name="footer" ></frame>
```

Then I have the groovy page classes like this

```
class myMainPage extends Page {
   static content = {
       myModule{module FrameModule}
   }
 }


class FrameModule extends Module {
     def FrameElement 
     static content = {
     Myframe { $('frame', name:'center') }
     FrameElement {Myframe.find('input[name="quantity"]')}
     myQuantity = FrameElement.module(TextInput)
     myQuantity.text = '10'
  }

}
```

I tested this like this

```
Then:

   to myMainPage
 and:
     myModule.myQuantity
```

with setup of the module I get

> no such property TextInput for class: FrameModule

How do I manipulate those frame's element

Comment: Please look at http://gebish.org/manual/current/#dealing-with-frames Your FrameModule code looks strange could you make sure that this is the exact code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to import

```
import geb.module.TextInput
```

unless you did do that and just didn't include it in your post.

Actually, looking more closely, you should eliminate your FrameElement, and instead declare myQuantity like below. This will eliminate some fluff and simplify it into one line that finds the element and instantiates it as a TextInput module.

```
myQuantity = {$("input", name: "quantity").module(TextInput)}
```

Than you should be able to do myModule.myQuantity like you are currently doing.